# E: Package 'maven2' has no installation candidate

Tags: 14.04, apt

I am trying to install maven with `sudo apt-get install maven2`

Should be pretty straightforward, but I am getting this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package maven2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  maven

E: Package 'maven2' has no installation candidate
```

Any hint?

Thanks

Comment: Please don't cross-post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39725856/linux-package-%C2%B4maven2%C2%B4-has-no-installation-candidate

Comment: which ubuntu version is this ?

Comment: As for the actual problem, have you tried running `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: @Amias - You can see from the tags it's 14.04

Comment: `maven2` appears to be in the `universe` repo, so make sure that is enabled and then run `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: how can I make sure thats enabled? Tried apt-get update but not working

Comment: @stackman - See this post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository

Comment: @AndroidDev Thanks, its a must-read post, but unfortunately not working this time

Comment: Not working how?

Answer (score 1):

`maven2` package is in universe repository http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=maven2. So, you need to enable universe repo.

- [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Then use

```
sudo apt-get update
```

to update software index.

Then use

```
sudo apt-get install maven2
```

to install it